# Link 2 attributes in a database

Tags: python, database, content-management-system

We are looking for advice to find a solution to this problem :

We consider that we have the following database table

```
Article (id, title, content)
```

We store 2 articles on this table

```
article1(1, title1, content1)
article2(2, title2, content2)
```

The primary key is the id and we want to know if there is a way to "link" the article2.title with the article1.title. For example, if the articles have the same title, we want to use only one entry so article2.title should be a kind of pointer to article1.title. The system will check the data before storing it in the database and if title2 = title1, a link should be created without inserting the title2.

There is a way to do that with Python and any database management system ?

It's for a school project, so any help will be really appreciated

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is RDBS 101 but I'll answer anyway. Setup some schema like this:

```
article
    id
    title_id
    content

title
    id
    title
```

Then you can get the articles and titles using an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    article.id,
    title.title,
    article.content
FROM article 
INNER JOIN title ON
    title.id = article.title_id
```

I'll leave the inserts up to you, but it should be pretty obvious at this point.

As for a CMS and database ORM, I'd recommend [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org) respectively. However, Flask isn't a CMS, but rather a lightweight web framework that's easy to learn and use.